# Symmetry of the plane

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry

> Consider the symmetry group of the plane. Suppose $f$ is an element and has finite order. Show that $f$ has a fixed point. Classify all such $f$.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I can't figure out how to relate finite order with fixed points. I want someone to help me out in this.

Note that in the original question, there were two more parts to this question namely

> **a.** Find all elements of order $2$ in this group.
>
> **b.** Let $C$ be a polygon in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $f$ be a symmetry of $\mathbb R^2$. If $D=f(C)$, show that $f$ maps the centroid of $C$ to the centroid of $D$.

both of which I was able to solve. The answer to the first one is all reflections and rotation by $\pi$. These two parts may have some use in the original question, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun It was really framed as one single question from where I was solving it. So, I think, the first two parts may have some use in the third one. That's why I posted the question as I found it.

Comment: @Shaun please check whether this edit resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints

For (a) What does $f$ do to the midpoint of $(x, f(x))$? Then look for the set of fixed points.

For (b) the centroid is not equidistant from the vertices (look at a triangle that's not equilateral).

Comment: For (a), please elaborate a little bit. And, I changed (b)- please check the edit. Thanks for pointing that out. I was daydreaming a little while writing it :|

Comment: The first part of the hint in (a) finds fixed points from nonfixed points. That should help you show that the set of fixed points is a single point or a line.

Comment: Can you please be a little more elaborate... I still can't understand how the midpoint of $(x,f(x))$ relates to the elements of order $2$.

Comment: You know $f$ preserves distances. Use that fact to show that the image of a line is a line. If $x$ is a point of order $2$ what happens to the line joining $x$ to $f(x)$? Then what about the midpoint?

Comment: Okay, I understand now (+1). So, if $x$ is an element of order $2$, then the midpoint is a fixed point. Is that proof enough of the fact that it's either a rotation or a reflection? Also, any ideas about (c)?

Comment: No that's not proof enough, but it's the first big step. Use that to show that either there is one fixed point or a line of fixed points.  Then show those cases correspond to rotations and reflections.

Comment: Yes, so either it's the midpoint or the perpendicular bisector of the line joining $x$ and $f(x)$. If it's the former, then it's rotation by $\pi$ , and if it's the later, then it's reflection by that line. But, how do I show that there are no more?

Comment: If there are three noncolinear fixed points you should be able to prove everything is fixed.

Comment: Yes, and any ideas about (c)?